# How to limit coredump CPU usage?

Tags: cpu, core-dump

I have some process (test) which runs on my machine.
Sometimes it crashes and a core dump is generated.

Whilst the core dump is being written, the machine is completely frozen (even the mouse pointer cannot be moved).

I thought I could limit the CPU usage for the core-dump generation (I'm willing to accept a longer time to write the dump).

How can this be done? Is there a better solution?

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: of course, if you dont want the core, use `ulimit -c 0` to suppress it. Or perhaps if you run your program under gdb you can exploit the error without causing a dump?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to relevant bug reports (e.g., *[FS#41728 - [systemd] coredumps, 100% cpu usage, X hanging](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/41728)*  and *[systemd-coredump 100% CPU usage](https://forum.manjaro.org/index.php?topic=16765.0)*), core dumps in Linux are initiated in the kernel, with it copying the data out to userspace.  That is where the time goes.  You can generally interrupt things running as yourself, but not the kernel processes.

Further reading:

- [How to limit the write speed of core dump in linux , which would make the load dramatically high.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15107844/how-to-limit-the-write-speed-of-core-dump-in-linux-which-would-make-the-load-d)
- [So you want to write to a file real fast…](http://blog.plenz.com/2014-04/so-you-want-to-write-to-a-file-real-fast.html)
- [Crashdump Improvements for Larger Systems](http://events.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/LinuxFoundation_EEUS_0.pdf)